# How to get access token and refresh token after user login and consent in Google OAuth2?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-api-js-client

I want to import contacts of a `Gmail` user through the Google API.

**I have the following:**

1. Use `Client secret and key` to obtain the authorized url. This is the url which the user visits to allow permission for my app.
2. The authorized url redirects to the redirect uri specified in the App settings.
3. I have a query parameter `code` in the url and I am guessing this is the Authorized code that the docs say [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer).

**The problem:**

I want to exchange this code to obtain the `access token` and the `refresh token` through `javascript` if possible. But I can't see any docs for this part in `javascript`.

In my server side I am doing this to obtain the `authorized url`:

```
token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(client_id=settings.GMAIL_CLIENT_ID,
                                client_secret=settings.GMAIL_API_KEY,
                                scope=scope, user_agent=user_agent)

auth_url = token.generate_authorize_url(redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
```

and then redirecting the user to `auth_url`. Now once the user is allowing the requested permissions they are redirected back to my site with the query parameter `code`. I want to use `javascript` from here to get the `access token`.

The other option is to get the `access token` in the server side once the user is redirected to my site and return it to him along with the response but I dont really want to do this.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: if you want to use OAuth2 client-side authentication, you're using the wrong documentation.

Now the details.

OAuth2 has 4 grant types:

1. **Authorization Code**,
2. **Implicit**,
3. **Resource Owner Password Credentials** and
4. **Client Credentials**

If you want more details, you can read [this nice post](http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/a-guide-to-oauth-2-grants/) with explanation.

You've pointed the Google docs for `OAuth2 for Web Servers`, which fits **Authorization Code** type. It relies on Web Server data exchange over SSL, because it involves exchange the `client_secret`.

I.e, if you try do the POST request to get the `access_token` using JavaScript, you'll expose your `client_secret`, as it's a required parameter in the POST call.

If you want try request the `access_token` not using server side code, you need to use the **Implicit** grant type.

You can find Google documentation for Implicit grant type in [Using OAuth 2.0 for Client-side Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent)